# Android: Theme is not working

Tags: android, xml, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to apply a theme to android activity

themes.xml

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="CableTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="textViewStyle">@style/Textview</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="Textview" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">22.0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
</style>
```

Attrs.xml

```
<attr name="textViewStyle" format="reference" />
```

1) CableTheme is the applicaition theme . I expect all the textview should be in 22dp size and blue in color in the activity.But it is not rendering.

2) I want apply a style like text size 20 to all the textview in my activity . If above is not the correct procedure to apply theme. How can i do it?

Comment: Did you set CableTheme in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yes ::: if you have a sample app for theme rendering .. that would be great full:)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Textview</item>
```

the attribute `textViewStyle` is from the framework. Therefore you have to put in the 'android' namespace before that.

Remove the `textViewStyle` attribute you defined yourself.